# Increment a variable by constant in recursive rules in prolog

Tags: prolog

**Here's the line of code written in prolog to make an lcm (Least Common Multiple) rule:**

```
lcm(A, B, A) :-
    A > B,
    A mod B =:= 0, 
    !.

lcm(A, B, B) :-
    B > A,
    B mod A =:= 0,
    !.

lcm(A, B, X) :-
    A < B,
    ImproveB is B + B,
    lcm(A, ImproveB, X).

lcm(A, B, X) :-
    A > B,
    ImproveA is A + A,
    lcm(ImproveA, B, X).
```

I noticed that there's a bug in these lines of code.

*For example, the case is lcm(16,10,X) which operated as below:*

1. lcm(16,10,X).
2. lcm(32,10,X).
3. lcm(64,10,X).
4. lcm(128,10,X).
5. ...

*It will double the larger number and not increment it by the expected constant. The expected operation is as below:*

1. lcm(16,10,X).
2. lcm(32,10,X).
3. lcm(48,10,X).
4. lcm(64,10,X).
5. lcm(80,10,X).
6. since 80 mod 10 is 0, so the result of X is 80

So, how to handle this situation?

Comment: Why should the multiplication with two (`ImproveA is A + A`) yield a result that is the same, even if only odd numbers are involved? Think of `lcm(3,5,X)`.

Comment: Sorry, Sir, I don't think I get the point well since English is not my first lang. But from what I get, I think it is because of the "recurrence" parameter, instead of incrementing it with a constant value which is the largest number between two initial inputs, it will double the "predecessor of the recurrence".

Comment: For case lcm(3,5,X), ImproveA should be written as A + 5. If it is written as A + A, it will not pass to step lcm(3, 15, X) which is 15, but it will operate like lcm(3,5,X)->lcm(3,10,X)->lcm(3,20,X),etc. 
But if I write ImproveA is A + 5 for all cases, it won't be applied to many other cases like lcm(14,10,X) which instead increment with 14, it will increment by 5.

Comment: In brief, my question is how to implement ImproveA  (which when implemented as ImproveA is A+A it will double it and not increment it by constant, but when implemented as ImproveA is A + 5, it will increment it by 5 which is constant but cant be applied for most other cases if the increment value needed is not 5, but 6, 7,etc.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem, the constant value to be added must be passed as an *extra* argument (which **does not change**). Also, to reduce the number of clauses, you can *fix* the order of the arguments so that the first one is the maximum and the second one is the minimum:

```
lcm(A, B, C) :-
    Min is min(A, B),
    Max is max(A ,B),
    lcm_loop(Max, Min, Max, C).

lcm_loop(A, B, K, C) :-
    (   A mod B =:= 0
    ->  C = A
    ;   A1 is A + K,
        lcm_loop(A1, B, K, C)  ).
```